# How to tell stringstream to ignore null terminating character?

Tags: c++, istream

Is there any way to tell a stringstream to ignore a null terminating char and read a certain amount of chars anyway?

As you can see from this minimum example, even though the char array consists of 3 chars, the stringstream terminates at the second position:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        char test[3];
        test[0] = '1';
        test[1] = '\0';
        test[2] = '2';

        stringstream ss(test);

        char c;
        cout << "start" << endl;
        while (ss.get(c)) {
                cout << c << endl;
        }

        if (ss.eof()) {
                cout << "eof" << endl;
        }
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 
start
1
eof
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is not about stringstreams. The problem is you are implicitly constructing a `std::string` from a `const char*` for that stringstream constructor argument, and doing so using the overload that expects a C-string. So, naturally, you should expect C-string-like behaviour.

Instead you can form the argument using the `std::string(const char*, std::size_t)` constructor, or send the data to a default-constructed stringstream using `.write`.

Comment: Very technical and correct, but asking a person *very new to C++* (me) to read the documentation is not helpful. I will refer to this meta discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261091/teaching-people-to-read-documentation

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I think a little unfair (unnecessary) on the documentation comment, I had to stare at this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream  for a good 30 seconds; it's not that clear and I knew  was looking for a conversion to `std::string`

Comment: @RichardCritten It's clear that there are no `char*` overloads at all and that therefore a string is being created, which takes you to the string ctor documentation which is again quite clear about what each one does.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer explaining the underlying problem (creating a `std::string` from a `char*`), here's one (of many) ways around the problem, using `std::string_literals`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
  using namespace std::string_literals;
  const std::string str_with_null = "1\0002"s;
  std::stringstream ss(str_with_null);
  char c;
  while (ss.get(c)) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << '\n';
  }
}
```

When run, this should print out:

```
49
0
50
```